# Regex, поиск шаблона с перестановками

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь тут https://regex101.com/r/YTiGuM/1 разобраться в регулярных выражениях и никак не могу сообразить как разобрать строку, если она может приходить с различным порядком элементов, например:

```
Ищу элементы "-Ку", "-ка", "-ре", "-ку".

-Ку-ка-ре-ку - полная фраза

-ка-Ку-ре - фраза с перестановкой и отсутствием одного элемента
```

На выходе хочется чтобы в совпадениях в поле Match была полная строка, а группы заполнялись найденными элементами не зависимо от их порядка и наличия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((-[КкАа]{2}+)|(-[КкУу]{2}+)|(-[РрЕе]{2}+))+
```

Comment: Это выражение работает. Пытаюсь продвинуться дальше и добавляю еще искомый элемент "-у". Фраза выглядит как "-Ку-ка-ре-ку-у", по аналогии меняю выражение на: ((-[КкАа]{2}+)|(-[КкУу]{2}+)|(-[РрЕе]{2}+)|(-[Уу]{1}+))+ 
И в результате для "-у" получается 2 группы. Что не правильно?

Comment: @Nova, первая группа получает последнее значение выражения. Я добавил ее для получения fullmatch. Если вы в коде используете дополнительно группы, то первую группу вы должны отбросить.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон `(-Ку|-ка|-ре|-ку)` находит в тексте (при активном модификаторе `g`) подстроки `-Ку`, `-ка`, `-ре` или `-ку`. Чтобы найти их *последовательные повторения*, нужно *квантифицировать* захватываемую группу с помощью квантификатора `+`, а чтобы получить только полные совпадения, заменить захватываемую группу незахватываемой:

```
(?:-Ку|-ка|-ре|-ку)+
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/aCTnCJ/1).

Если оптимизировать это выражение, можно использовать

```
/(?:-(?:к[уа]|ре|у))+/i
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/W3UsWk/1) (флаг `u` необходим в PHP при работе с шаблонами Юникода).

**Подробности**

- `(?:` - начало незахватываемой группы, которая необходима для захвата 1 и более повторений полного шаблона

  - `-` - дефис (все искомые части начинаются с него, поэтому эффективнее всего вынести его за скобки)
  - `(?:` - начало группы-контейнера, где можно указать все альтернативы
  - `к[уа]` - `ку` или `ка` (`[уа]` - это символьный класс, находящий `а` или `у`)
  - `|` - или
  - `ре` - подстрока `ре`
  - `|` - или
  - `у` - подстрока `у`
  - `)` - конец вложенной группы-контейнера
- `)+` - 1 и более повторов полного шаблона.